# How to change program from while loop to for loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes, do-while

I understand that `while` loops and `for` loops have different layouts in order to work. But I am stuck on how to convert this code to `for` loop format.

How do I change the format while keeping the same output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n, i =1, sum =0;
     do{
      printf("enter a positive number to find whether prime or not: ");
      scanf("%d",&n);
   } while (n<=0);
    while (i<=n){
       if (n%i ==0) sum+=1; //sum is the validation flag
      i+=1;
   }
   if (sum>2) printf("\nThe number %d  is not prime.", n);
   else
   printf("\nThe number %d is prime.", n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert this to for loop?

Comment: Why ? A do-while is much more readable than a for in your situation.

Comment: A `for` loop makes little sense if you're not incrementing something.

Comment: On the other hand, the `while` loop would make sense as a `for` loop.

Comment: @mrsrizan, This is for my class. I'm just as confused as you all are.

Comment: Are you sure the assignment wasn't about the `while (i <= n)` loop?

Comment: What is for your class? converting loops, or testing for primes? If the latter, your solution is inefficient: you can stop at the first divisor (<= its square root) with no remainder.

Comment: @Barmar, English isn't my professor's first language, because of this, Major typo's are in the instructions and it is oftentimes difficult to understand what he wants us to do.

Comment: It makes a big difference in this case, so you should try to find out for sure.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, this task is to change the `while (i <= n)` loop. If this is the case, how would I fix it?

Comment: BTW: `while (i<=n){` is very _slow_ for large `n` to find the count of primes.  `while (i < n/i) { if (n%i ==0) sum+=2; i++; } sum += (i == n/i);`  is _much_ faster.  Other improvements: quit loop when a non-trivial divisor is found.
`

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop is like a `while` loop, except that the iteration variable initialization and updating are put into the `for` header.

The initialization is the declaration `int i = 1` before the loop. The update is `i += 1` (which is usually written as `i++`). So take out these separate statements and put them into the header.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n%i == 0) {
        sum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation. I understand it might be difficult to teach beginners all the time. Hopefully soon I can become more educated in the language. This community is great, since my professor's first language is not english it can be very difficult to understand what he is trying to teach.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this do-while loop

```
 do{
  printf("enter a positive number to find whether prime or not: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
} while (n<=0);
```

then it can be rewritten as a for loop for example the following way.

```
 for ( n = 0; n <= 0; scanf("%d",&n) )
 {
      printf("enter a positive number to find whether prime or not: ");
 }
```

Pay attention to that this code snippet

```
    while (i<=n){
       if (n%i ==0) sum+=1; //sum is the validation flag
      i+=1;
   }
   if (sum>2) printf("\nThe number %d  is not prime.", n);
   else
   printf("\nThe number %d is prime.", n);
```

does not correctly determine whether a number is a prime number. For example for the number equal to 1 the output will be that the number is a prime number. Change the condition in the if statement like

```
   if (sum != 2) printf("\nThe number %d  is not prime.", n);
```

As for the while loop then it can be rewritten the following way

```
for ( ; i<=n; i++ ){
   if (n%i ==0) sum+=1; //sum is the validation flag
}
```

Also as the variable i is used only within the loop then it is better to declare it in the for loop like

```
for ( int i = 1; i<=n; i++ ){
   if (n%i ==0) sum+=1; //sum is the validation flag
}
```

In this case remove the declaration of the variable i from this like

```
int n, i =1, sum =0;
```

at least like

```
int n, sum =0;
```

Comment: I made a mistake, the professor is looking to change the `while (i<=n)` loop. Sorry.

Comment: @misfit101 See my updated answer.